# Динамический контент и его подгрузка

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

На странице администратора есть меню и блок adm_task,где отображается основной контент [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как по клику на меню изменялся только основной контент(принимая соответствующие данные) и как рендерить эти блоки

Comment: для начала надо понимать на чем именно у вас фронт. это react, vue или что-то другое? сам процесс рендеринга можно организовать многими путями от получения с сервера готовых html-блоков до получения данных в json и далее их обработки на фронте.

Comment: Фронт написан на обычном pug

Comment: это шаблонизатор, он просто переводит html в более простой вид. речь про вашу фронтэнд-архитектуру, какой технологический стек?

Comment: фронт -html,css,js,  бек- node js

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, у вас все написано на чистом js, без использования фреймворков и библиотек?

Если так, то схема простая:

1. делаете роутинг по нужным вам path's (по ссылкам в вашем меню). можно все прописать вручную, но лучше использовать express или что-то в этом роде.
2. далее на каждом маршруте выдаете скомпилированный html-шаблон.

Например для Express-сервера (делаем шаблон /views/hello_world.pug и прописываем в сервере):

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/'));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views/');
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('hello_world');
});
```

Также надо заполнить этот шаблон данными из БД. Конкретный код зависит от типа используемой БД.

Comment: это же изменит страницу полностью, разве нет?

Comment: тут 2 варианта: или компилировать шаблон на сервере (для этого используйте вложенный шаблон pug для нужной вам страницы) или динамически все обновлять на фронте.